# Не получается сделать commit (Unversioned files) Pycharm GitHub

Tags: git, github, pycharm, git-commit

Как вернуть статус этим файлам чтобы модно было их commit на gitHub?
Выдает, что я не могу сделать коммит этих файлов

[image: unversioned files]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А случаем у вас нету в проекте .gitignore файла, в котором прописано, что файлы такого типо не передаются ?

Comment: @WilteRatenau Этот файл присутсвует но он пустой

Comment: Тогда Вам стоит так же посмотреть обучающие материалы как с этими файлами работать в рамках django проекта. Так как миграции и файлы бд Вам не нужны будут при деплое и есть static файлы которые тоже не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас PyCharm показывает 5к+ unrevisioned files - просто добавлять их все в git будет очень плохой идеей.

В проектах (особенно новых) обычно не бывает такого количества файлов, скорее всего это файлы виртуального окружения, кэша, файлы IDE и т.д. В первую очередь нужно, чтобы это все игнорировалось, для этого все не нужное надо добавить в файл `.gitignore`.

За основу можно взять этот шаблон: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore

Естественно, его нужно переименовать, так, чтобы осталось только `.gitignore`.
В самом файле я обычно раскомментирую последнюю строку `.idea/` (игнорирование файлов проекта PyCharm или IntellijIDEA).

После добавления этого файла количество Unrevisioned files должно стать сильно меньше, при коммите через PyCharm ставьте галку  на Unrevisioned files (пустой квадрат слева от этой надписи - это чекбокс), и коммитите.

Либо через консоль делаете `git add .`, потом коммитите. Без разницы как именно вы добавите эти файлы (поставив галку на них или через `git add .`), суть одна и та же.

Comment: Просьба обратить внимание на [вопрос на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12934/176217) и по возможности оставить комментарий или ответ.

Answer (score -3):

Прописав в терминале команду ниже, все файлы поменяли цвет и коммит получается сделать.

```
git add .
```